# How to prevent Google Chrome from circumventing the default browser settings?

Tags: firefox, chrome, browser, alternatives

After I installed Google Chrome on my work laptop, Pidgin links open with Chrome even though Firefox is set as my default browser.  Pidgin is using `sensible-browser` to open links.  How can I get `sensible-browser` to use the default browser?

I found a couple of posts about similar problems [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1715582) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2212948) but the solutions seemed to be "run a bunch of random commands and one of them might possibly fix the issue".  I need to understand what the underlying problem is before I can take any steps to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sensible-browser` does the following:

1. if the `BROWSER` environment variable contains anything, it splits the value using `:` and each substring is tried as a candidate for a browser (so you can set `BROWSER` to be your favourite browser's executable);
2. if you're running GNOME, it tries running `gnome-www-browser`, which you can configure using `update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser` (as root) to point to your favourite browser;
3. if that fails, or you're not running GNOME, it tries running `x-www-browser`, which you can configure using `update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` (as root) to point to your favourite browser;
4. if that fails, it tries running `www-browser`, which you can configure using `update-alternatives --config www-browser` (as root) to point to your favourite browser (but it's supposed to be a text-mode browser such as Lynx or W3M).

None of the alternatives take their value from your desktop environment's default; that explains why they ignore the browser you've configured.